# laravel Auth attempt parameters issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code:

```
if(!empty($email) && !empty($password))
                {
                    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'activated' => 1)))
                    {
                        return Redirect::route('home');
                    }else{
                        return Redirect::route('signin')->with('message', 'Login Failed. Please try again.');
                    }
                }else{
                    return Redirect::route('error');
                }
```

The above is the login function of my application. The login view loads and user enters date and above is executed. Auth::attempt is passed a third parameter above to check if activated field in table is 1. It throws a weird error and this is it:

[image]

Please help me understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app/model/User.php` file is missing a closing bracket `}`. That is what the debug tool is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just missing a closing } on your function or class.

The error unexpected end means php finished processing the file but something hasn't been closed (php was expecting more), and because it's expecting a function this means the class hasn't been closed.